# What will happen if 0 is passed to %s in printf()?

Tags: c, printf

I understand that passing a null pointer will trigger an undefined behavior, but if I use `calloc()` to initialize a char array and print it, for example:

```
char * a = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
printf("%s\n", a);
```

`calloc()` should initialized the char array to 0. Since in ASCII table 0 refers to NULL, I expected undefined behavior. However, every time I run it, it will actually print nothing. Is this output fixed? Can I reason about the output?

Comment: It's the empty string (`""`). No problemo!

Comment: In your code example, `a` will hold the start address of your allocated buffer. This address is obviously not NULL. Only the value that `a` points to is zero, which is not a problem since zero is the string terminator in C.

Comment: The null *character* and the null *pointer* are two different concepts, which unfortunately have the same name. A null pointer can't be dereferenced and passing a null pointer as argument would lead to *undefined behavior*. But passing a valid pointer to the first element of an array initialized with the byte zero is the same as passing any empty string (the null *character* is the same as `'\0'` which is the string terminator).

Comment: To summarize, your initialization is somewhat equivalent to `char a[10] = "";`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I now understand why it prints out nothing.

Comment: The `printf()` statement should print a newline — I presume it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C a string is generally understood to terminate at the first 0 byte encountered. Since the first byte in the result of `calloc` has value 0, it is interpreted as immediately ending the string, leaving you with the empty string.